# Translate a plugin using .po .mo files

Tags: plugins, translation, localization

I want to translate [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/) plugin.

The plugin has already been translated into other languages and it has `.pot` files for adding new languages (as far as I understood from description).

How do I create `.po` and `.mo` files for my new language and make them accessible so as to be used by the plugin? I've tried to define Russian language in my `wp-config.php` file by inserting the definition below:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'ru_RU');
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### The Editor

There are others, but this is most used: [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/download.php), a cross-platform gettext catalogs (.po files) editor.

#### The Formats

- `.mo` stands for Machine Object
  -- compiled export of the `.po` file which is used by WordPress
- `.po` stands for Portable Object
  -- editable text file with the translations strings
  -- based on the master `.pot` file, using *Update from POT file* PoEdit function
  -- some folks distribute this as a master file, but it should be used only for translations
- `.pot` stands for Portable Object Template
  -- editable text file used to grab all the translatable strings from WordPress itself and Themes and Plugins, using *Update from Sources* PoEdit function

#### The Procedure

- Duplicate the .pot file and rename it to `plugin-basename-lang_COUNTRY.po`
- Example for the referenced plugin case: ***`subscribe-reloaded-pt_BR.po`***
  -- **pt_BR** means Portuguese Brazil, but many languages don't have a country variation...
  -- you'll have to fill in with your own language
- [`WPLANG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language) in `wp-config.php` file must be set to your language, e.g., `pt_BR`
- Every time you save the `.po` file, PoEdit automatically generates a `.mo` file, which is the one WordPress uses and basically the only one you need to upload

#### Observations

- If you do a full or a decent partial translation, submit it to the plugin author so he can include it in the Repository and you [get credited](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/other_notes/) for it
- Don't forget to make a backup of your translation, because if you upgrade the plugin your file will be lost
- @user17078 plugin suggestion is quite nice, but I never used it much

Comment: How long is the new mo/po file supposed to take to have effect?

Answer (score 9):

(Here is an EXAMPLE of translation to DEUTSCH. CHANGE the customs to YOUR DESIRED ones.)

in every plugins head, there is an unique name. 
(for example:

```
/*
Plugin Name: my-pluginname
.......
*/
```

then, in that plugin's folder, create a folder "languages";

then, into your plugin .php file (somewhere in the top), insert the initialization code:

```
class load_language 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    add_action('init', array($this, 'load_my_transl'));
    }

     public function load_my_transl()
    {
        load_plugin_textdomain('my-pluginname', FALSE, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/languages/');
    }
}

$zzzz = new load_language;
```

then open any text editor, then insert like this code (NOTE, THAT we are only adding two sample messages, "hello" and "bye", so , you can ADD AS MANY messages AS YOU WANT with the similar lines).

```
# English translations for PACKAGE package.
# Copyright (C) 2012 THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# Automatically generated, 2012.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: my-pluginname 1.0\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2012-08-06 13:46-0400\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2013-03-21 11:20+0400\n"
"Last-Translator: Automatically generated\n"
"Language-Team: none\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: iso-8859-1\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.5.4\n"


#: mypluginindex.php:87 (it is just a line of a note, to remind where our code appears)
msgid "mymessage1"
msgstr "Hello"

#: mypluginindex.php:88
msgid "mymessage2"
msgstr "Bye"
```

then save this file as "my-pluginname-en_US.po" (note, that .po is an extension of file, so check that your text editor program has not saved to "my-pluginname-en_US.po.TXT").

then  download POEDIT software, and open this  file. then edit the "translation" field, and then save as "my-pluginname-de_DE"
there will be generated two files ( If poEdit does not generate the second .mo file automatically, just go to File -> Preferences -> Editor and check the box that says "Automatically compile .mo file on save"),

then put those two file into "languages" folder.

after this, open wp-config.php and find this code:

```
define ('WPLANG, '');
```

and change to

```
define ('WPLANG, 'de_DE');
```

That's all.
When WordPress is loaded, it will read your plugins language file, with prefix -de_DE.

So, in the plugin's .php file, instead of:

```
echo "Something string";
```

you should use:

```
echo __("mymessage1", 'my-pluginname');
```

Finished. Now you should test your plugin.

p.s. used links:

- [codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)
- [codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress)
- [codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)
- [codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language)

Comment: I tried this with my theme.  In header.php, I have `echo __("thanks-for-visiting", 'transparent');`.  In theme\languages\transparent-en_US.po, I have `msgid "thanks-for-visiting"` 
`msgstr "Hello!  Thank you for visiting.  Take a look around and subscribe to the "`.  This outputs "thanks-for-visiting" on the front end.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this [codestyling-localization plugin:](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/). You can translate you plugins and themes using this.

Comment: This is the best translation plugin I have ever seen. This plugin can own poedit anyday and the best part is that it is free and user-friendly. This answer should be voted up atleast.

Comment: No longer exists.

Comment: This looks like a good alternative: https://wordpress.org/plugins/say-what/

Comment: @jetlej interesting, doesn't seem to work for my po file though :/

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use [POEdit](http://www.poedit.net/). It's a free application for creating .po/.mo files.

I wrote a pretty in-depth tutorial on the entire topic [here](http://pippinsplugins.com/localizing-and-translating-wordpress-plugins/?). You can skip to Step 3 - Create the Translation File For Text Domain.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest also h[ttp://poeditor.com/](http://poeditor.com/). It is a web-based translation tool that works great with .po, .mo, .pot and other types of files.

Comment: A visitor proposed an edit pointing to a new plugin for this service: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/poeditor/

Comment: poeditor.com not longer exists...