# What is a Theme textdomain?

Tags: theme-development, translation, textdomain

I've found that any WordPress theme uses this functions, but I don't understand what is the purpose of it and what is it, in this case `'themify'`?
Here are some examples in Themify `functions.php`:

1).

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'themify', TEMPLATEPATH.'/languages' );
```

2).

```
if (function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'main-nav' => __( 'Main Navigation', 'themify' ),
            'footer-nav' => __( 'Footer Navigation', 'themify' ),
        ) );
    }
```

And in tempate file:

3). `<?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing found.', 'themify' ); ?>`

And many more! My doubt is what is `'themify'` stand for? What is their purpose? Could I Change it or delete it? What is the place, `'themify'`, for?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this case, `'themify'` is the defined *textdomain* for the Theme, used to [make the Theme *translatable*](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers). (Codex reference: [**`load_theme_textdomain()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain)).

Making a Theme translation-ready requires a few steps.

1. Define the Theme's *textdomain*:

   ```
   load_theme_textdomain( 'themify', TEMPLATEPATH.'/languages' );
   ```
2. Define *translatable strings* in the template.

   This is done using one of a few translation functions: [**`__()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) (for *returned* strings), [**`_e()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) (for *echoed* strings), and [**`_x()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x)/[**`_ex()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_ex) (for *gettext context* strings). There are others, but you get the idea...

   A static text string, such as `<p>Hello world!</p>`, is wrapped in an appropriate translation function, such as `<p><?php _e( 'Hello World!', 'themify' ); ?></p>`, to make it available for translation.
3. Generate the .mo/.po files
   <sub>*reference on [how to edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57219) language files*</sub>

Comment: @SokVanrithy, refer to [this Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57219/12615) for how to handle `.mo/.po` files. (Chip, I haven't added the link into your Answer as you may have another recommendation:)

Comment: @brasofilo feel free to add it if you'd like. I think it's out of scope for the question as-asked, but still useful information.

Comment: Why would you change it? Are you forking the Theme?

Comment: Yes, I want to get rid of them. I've downloaded a theme from Webdesigndepot, and it calls `base theme`. I asked the author that would I be able change the orginal codes? They're allowed because it is the base blank theme for whom who wanna have the structure for the custom theme. In addition, it's the present from the author there to give to the reader. My doubt is like above!

Comment: Sure, you *can* get rid of them; but it also doesn't hurt just to *leave* them. You can even change the `textdomain` to a different string, to reference your forked Theme. Development best practices include making Themes translatable, so I would advise *against* removing them entirely. That said, you certainly *can*, if you choose to.

Comment: Hey Chip, where is a common place for a theme to have the load_theme_textdomain call? I need to find the text domain for a theme I am working with.

Comment: "*...where is a common place for a theme to have the load_theme_textdomain call?*" - in `functions.php`, ideally inside a callback hooked into `after_setup_theme`.