# Language translation on a fresh english installation

Tags: plugins, multi-language, language

i need to translate an english wordpress installation to italian language,but i would like to mantain both languages en/english, so the user can choose which to turn on fron the frontend side.
I need italian as default language and english for choice, i would like to know if is it possible to have them without re-installing the wp, and how to do that?

Does i need to translate some file manually? or some plugin extension could help me?

Definitely i would like Italian language for Backend, and Eng/Ita (choose) for frontend side.

I Installed a third parties theme, don't know if this could help on translation :/

Any suggestion appriaciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you need English in the backend and Italian in the frontend?

Comment: @brasofilo better italian in BE and eng/ita in FRONT ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the documentation for more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language

*Skip the first two steps and the backend won't be translated.*

1) Download the [Italian version](http://it.wordpress.org/) of WordPress.

2) Upload the files located in `/wp-content/languages/` to your live site. These files are for translating the **Backend**.

3) Define the language in `wp-config.php` as `define ('WPLANG', 'it_IT');`. Before uploading the new version of `wp-config.php`, make a backup of the version in the live site.

4) The frontend translation is done by your theme and it needs the file: `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/language/domainpath-it_IT.mo`.

5) Much probably this file doesn't exist, and you have to translate it yourself. The same goes for any plugin that renders content that needs translation. Normally the translation files are inside a folder called `languages`, but it could be `lang` or similar.

6) The easiest way to translate theme/plugins is to use this plugin: [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/). Or you can use the software PoEdit, more info in [this Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57243/12615).

Comment: To swap the languages in the frontend, we enter in another territory, as we are dealing with the Theme files **and** the content of the site.

Comment: great man! great answer! i'll try your steps!